# Tensorflow boolean_mask with dynamic mask

Tags: tensorflow, shapes, mask

The documentation of boolean_mask says that the shape of the mask must be known statically. But if you do

```
mask.set_shape([None])
tf.boolean_mask(tensor, mask)
```

it seems to work fine. Is there any reason to not do this?

Comment: The [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/boolean_mask) says the dimensionality of the mask must be known statically, not the whole shape.

Comment: If I don't use set_shape, I get the following error:   File "C:\Users\abc\Anaconda3\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\array_ops.py", line 1192, in boolean_mask
    "Number of mask dimensions must be specified, even if some dimensions"
ValueError: Number of mask dimensions must be specified, even if some dimensions are None.  E.g. shape=[None] is ok, but shape=None is not.

Comment: `shape=None` means the shape is completely unknown, including the number of dimensions. `shape=[None]` means the shape is 1-D, with an unknown number of elements.

Comment: So tensorflow can't compute the shape of the mask when the graph is built, so it's fine to set the shape to [None] when I am sure that the mask will have one dimension?

Comment: Yes, that's right!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looking at the [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/boolean_mask) closely reveals that it concerns the *dimensionality* of the mask, not its whole shape:

> `mask`: K-D boolean tensor, K <= N and K must be known statically.

Your mask now has size `None`, meaning its static shape is completely unknown, including the dimension. Your options are to either to ensure that the dimensionality of the mask is statically known (e.g., make sure its produced by an operation whose output dimensions are known, or feed a placeholder with known dimensions), or to enforce information about the size that you know, but that cannot be inferred at time of the construction of the computational graph. The latter you can do by [`set_shape`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Tensor#set_shape).

When you run `mask.set_shape([None])`, you are enforcing an assumption that the dimensionality of the mask will always be 1 (since `None` is in brackets), although the number of elements is unknown. If you are certain that your mask will always be 1-dimensional, this is fine to do.