# Is there a way to do the same thing in tensorflow as it's done below in numpy?

Tags: python, tensorflow

By using numpy, I could index an array as below

```
x[mask==1]
```

Assuming `x` and `mask` are both numpy array and `mask` contains only `1` and `0`.

Now I have both `x` and `mask` as `Tensor`s and want to mimic above behavior. What should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `boolean_mask`.

*Example*:

```
x = tf.constant([[1,2],[3,4]])
mask = tf.constant([[1,0],[0,1]])
tf.boolean_mask(x, tf.equal(mask, 1)).eval()
# array([1, 4])
```

Comment: when `mask` is a placeholder of unknown shape, I received an error message said `Number of mask dimensions must be specified, even if some dimensions are None.  E.g. shape=[None] is ok, but shape=None is not.` How could I solve it?

Comment: @SherwinChen you cannot use a completely unknown shape. The dimensionality of the placeholder must be known, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48978984/tensorflow-boolean-mask-with-dynamic-mask

Comment: Thank you, I've got rid of it :)

Answer (score 1):

This will give you a bolean mask

```
 import tensorflow as tf
 a = tf.Variable( [1,2,3,1] )   
 comparison = tf.equal( a, tf.constant( 1 ) )  
 start_op = tf.global_variables_initializer()    
 with tf.Session() as session:
   session.run(tart_op)

  print(session.run(comparison))

[ True False False  True]
```