# Using boolean_mask in custom loss function keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

The issue and error:
    `ValueError: Number of mask dimensions must be specified, even if some dimensions are None.  E.g. shape=[None] is ok, but shape=None is not.`

The story:

I was forced to implement a custom loss function is order to deal with the issue that I have "empty" label rows in my data - I can't find a way to implement dynamic output shapes.

A (very small sample output):

```
True
[[[0, 1, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
Predict
[[0.1, 0.65, 0.1, 0.1, 0.05], [0.01, .99, 0, 0, 0]]
```

In this sample, the second item is just a padded blank.
As such, my input shape is (None, 50, 300), and my (fixed) output is (None, 50, 5).

```py
def myLoss(y_true, y_pred):
    
    intermediate_tensor = tf.math.reduce_sum(tf.abs(y_true), 1)
    zero_vector = tf.zeros(shape=(1,1), dtype=tf.int64)
    bool_mask = tf.squeeze(tf.not_equal(intermediate_tensor, zero_vector))
    print(y_true)
    print(y_pred)
    print(intermediate_tensor)
    print(bool_mask)
    omit_true = tf.boolean_mask(y_true, bool_mask)
    omit_pred = tf.boolean_mask(y_pred, bool_mask)
    
    loss = tf.keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy()
    return loss(omit_true, omit_pred)
```

I just have no real idea how to fix this issue....

Answer (score 0):

A solution to your problem is to notably follow the advice from https://stackoverflow.com/a/48986289/11194702. As you know the boolean mask will be 1-dimensional, you need to set its shape with `.set_shape([None])`.

```
def myLoss(y_true, y_pred):
    
    intermediate_tensor = tf.math.reduce_sum(tf.abs(y_true), 1)
    zero_vector = tf.zeros(shape=(1,1), dtype=tf.int64)
    bool_mask = tf.reshape(tf.not_equal(intermediate_tensor, zero_vector), (-1,))
    bool_mask.set_shape([None])

    print(y_true)
    print(y_pred)
    print(intermediate_tensor)
    print(bool_mask)
    omit_true = tf.boolean_mask(y_true, bool_mask)
    omit_pred = tf.boolean_mask(y_pred, bool_mask)
    
    loss = tf.keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy()
    return loss(omit_true, omit_pred)
```

Answer (score -1):

Without going into more detail than I can comprehend (and thus explain), the loss function exists in graph mode. In graph mode, batch doesn't have a dimension, since it hasn't been defined yet.

The solution is to use tf.py_function, which lets you call an explicitly non-graph function, (and thus you know the dimension there).